# Get query with Sum and Percent WHERE data grouped by value

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, percentage

This is my table:

| Type | Creature | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HP Universe | Witches/Wizards | 100,000 |
| HP Universe | Muggles | 250,000 |
| HP Universe | Others | 75,000 |
| Other Universe | Witches/Wizards | 500,000 |
| Other Universe | Muggles | 1,000,000 |
| Other Universe | Others | 175 |

I used this query to get my table:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN type LIKE '%hp%' THEN 'HP Universe'
ELSE 'Other Universe' 
END AS Type, 
CASE WHEN creature LIKE '%witches%' THEN 'Witches/Wizards'
WHEN creature LIKE '%muggle%' THEN 'Muggles'
ELSE 'Others' 
END AS Creature,
COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) AS Population
FROM `table`
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I want to add another column called `pct_population` totals up the `population` by `type` and then gives me the percent by `creature`.

Basically, I want my table to look like this:

| Type | Creature | Population | Pct_Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP Universe | Witches/Wizards | 100,000 | 23.5% |
| HP Universe | Muggles | 250,000 | 58.82% |
| HP Universe | Others | 75,000 | 17.68% |
| Other Universe | Witches/Wizards | 500,000 | 33.32% |
| Other Universe | Muggles | 1,000,000 | 66.65% |
| Other Universe | Others | 175 | 0.01% |

We are basically totaling the `population` of each `type` and then breaking down the percentage by the `creature`.

I am not sure how to add that to my query.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @stickybit, those are not images. I added those using the `GitHub-flavored markdown format`. I have also added my desired table in the tabular format. I just needed help on how to get the `Pct_Population` column

Comment: @nb_nb_nb: I never said they were, I have that in just in case. But they aren't DDL and DML either and they are not even describing the *input* data before the query which is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `count(distinct type_id)`?  Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, the syntax clearly indicates BQ so I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can benefit from  `window function`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN type LIKE '%hp%' THEN 'HP Universe'
    ELSE 'Other Universe' 
    END AS Type 
    , CASE WHEN creature LIKE '%witches%' THEN 'Witches/Wizards'
    WHEN creature LIKE '%muggle%' THEN 'Muggles'
    ELSE 'Others' 
    END AS Creature
    , COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) AS Population
    , COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) / count(*) over (partition by CASE WHEN creature LIKE '%witches%' THEN 'Witches/Wizards'  WHEN creature LIKE '%muggle%' THEN 'Muggles' ELSE 'Others' END AS Creature)* 100.0 AS Pct_Population
FROM `table`
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```